# Date of Birth drop downs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am wanting to create three select boxes for a user's date of birth in a CakePHP app.

How do I do this? I have managed to build a Male or Female one using:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('gender', array('label' => '<strong>Gender</strong>', 'type' => 'select',
             'options' => array('Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female'))); ?>
```

But for a DoB one I'd need to pre-populate the fields with the month, days and year.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: @Cameron - Does CakePHP use PEAR HTML_QuickForms2?

Comment: Have you tried the [date input field](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements)?

Comment: Yes it just creates a text input field and not three drop downs

Comment: It should create three dropdowns. Is the field of type `date` in the database?

Comment: Why would the field type matter? As the Helper should just output what it is supposed to regardless of the form it is connected to. Also it isn't being told to create a 'type => select' so why would it create one?

Comment: That's not true. Cake checks field types and creates forms automatically of the correct type. (The field *does* exist in the database; the data doesn't but the field does.) You just have to create the form with the correct model (`$this->Form->create( 'User' )` or whatever the model's name is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need is a DB field called "birthday" or whatever which is of type "date".

```
echo $this->Form->input('birthday');
```

thats it

i recommend adding empty=>'- -' to the options array, though.

I also use min and max for years which is quite helpful:

```
'minYear'=>date('Y')-USER_AGE_MAX, 'maxYear'=>date('Y')-USER_AGE_MIN+1
```

whereas those two constants are defined in my bootstrap. you could also use Configure::write() and read() for it. max is in my case 99 and min 9

for a "german" form it would then be

```
echo $this->Form->input('birthday', array('dateFormat'=>'DMY', 'minYear'=>date('Y')-USER_AGE_MAX, 'maxYear'=>date('Y')-USER_AGE_MIN+1, 'empty'=>array('- -')));
```

Comment: See Facebook.com/r.php for an example of what I mean. I don't want a textbox.

Comment: The above example wouldn't generate a text box. It would generate the exact same thing as on rthe Facebook registration page as long as the database field type was a date field. Cake is clever like that :-)